# How to get the string between a fixed word and a fixed pattern

Tags: python, string

My string is like this "Bar Z1050,c105 cpt 100580 prov 056875" , I need to extract "bar","cpt","prov" as key and "Z1050,c105" "100580" "056875" as their respective values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split and zip:

```
s = "Bar Z1050,c105 cpt 100580 prov 056875"
w = s.split(' ')

d = dict(zip(w[::2], w[1::2]))
print(d)

# Output
{'Bar': 'Z1050,c105', 'cpt': '100580', 'prov': '056875'}
```

Comment: It _can_ also be turned into the oneliner `d = dict(zip((w := s.split(' '))[::2], w[1::2]))` using the walrus operator, but I wouldn't recommend it. Just for fun I guess :)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal. I'm totally agree. I would use walrus operator but readability counts (The zen of Python) :-)

Comment: I always try to challenge myself on how short you can make code from time to time, but it's obviously not practical. Just testing to see what the limits are.

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "Bar Z1050,c105 cpt 100580 prov 056875"
dict1 = {}
ls = str1.split(' ')
dict1 = {}
for index, x in enumerate(ls):
    if index%2!=0:
        dict1[x]=ls[index+1]
print(dict1)
```

Comment: This doesn't run. To make it work and be correct, you would need to use `if index%2==0: dict1.update({x: ls[index+1]})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def extract_kv_pairs(s, keys, values):
    pattern = r'\b(' + '|'.join(keys) + r')\b\s+(' + '|'.join(values) + r')'
    matches = re.findall(pattern, s)
    d = dict(matches)
    return d
    
s = "Bar Z1050,c105 cpt 100580 prov 056875"
keys = ['Bar', 'cpt', 'prov']
values = ['[\w,]+']
d = extract_kv_pairs(s, keys, values)
print(d)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).